# Puppeteer: How to use XPath and external Variable in evaluate function?

Tags: json, xpath, typeerror, puppeteer, evaluate

I am trying to use an XPath and an external variable in Puppeteer's evaluate function, but there is a problem:

- if I use the evaluate function with passing in the external variable then I can't pass in the XPath,
- if I remove the XPath everything is fine, but I need to do it with an XPath.

I just get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular
> structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'BrowserContext'
> |     property '_browser' -> object with constructor 'Browser'
> --- property '_defaultContext' closes the circle Are you passing a nested JSHandle?
> at JSON.stringify ()

This is my code (you can ignore the long XPath selector):

```js
let lastNameIn = await page.$x('//*[contains(translate(@placeholder,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), "LAST") and contains(translate(@placeholder,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), "NAME"))]')

lastname = "test"

await page.evaluate((lastname, lastNameIn) => { 
    el => el.value = lastname, lastNameIn[0]    
}, lastname, lastNameIn)
```

Comment: the solution is down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign only one value to `el.value`, then mark the element you want to evaluate at the first argument position: `lastNameIn[0]`, as a second argument you can add the dependency variable: `lastName` to the `pageFunction`.

See: [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args), `page.evaluate(pageFunction[, ...args])`.

```js
const lastNameIn = await page.$x("...");
const lastname = "test";

await page.evaluate((el, lastname) => { 
  el.value = lastname; 
}, lastNameIn[0], lastname);
```